# grep a string to another file

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files wherein:

cat A.txt

```
 5000000000000022805787
 5000000000009228662688
 5000000000009253546657
```

cat B.txt

```
 22805177, 22805179
 9228662680, 9228662689
 22805787, 22805789
```

output:

```
 9228662680, 9228662689
 22805787, 22805787
```

I want to grep numbers in A.txt (after zeroes) from B.txt. I have a code below but doesn't display an output.

```
 awk '{anum=substr($1,3,19); sub(/^0+/, "", anum); print anum}' A.txt | grep -nf B.txt
```

PS

```
 anum:
 2280578
 922866268
 925354665
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect to get the output? For example the number 22805187 is not in A.txt yet it shows up in the output.

Comment: By `9228662680, 9228662689` are you trying to range it from `9228662680` to `9228662689`? or you are comparing to each number?

Comment: For example, awk result is 922866268, just want to grep it from all records in B.txt, so the output will be 9228662680, 9228662689.

Comment: But how are you getting this line `22805187, 22805189` ? awk is not producing either of the numbers

Comment: Oh, im sorry. already updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing it in the other way round.

You need to search using the patterns produced by `awk`. So you can write something like

```
$ grep "$(awk '{anum=substr($1,3,19); sub(/^0+/, "", anum); print anum}' a)" b
9228662680, 9228662689
22805787, 22805789
```

**PS** You can do this thing entirely using `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dash to specify that the file is coming from the pipe

```
awk '{anum=substr($1,3,19); sub(/^0+/, "", anum); print anum}' A.txt | grep -f - B.txt
```

This outputs

```
9228662680, 9228662689
22805787, 22805789
```